How to get correct format for Solana wallet address private key?
I'm using Laravel and trying to work with Solana block chain
When I try to generate a wallet address I got the address right but the private key is not formatted correctly
This is my function below
public function generateWallet() { 
    try { 
        // Initialize the curve and generator 
        $adapter = EccFactory::getAdapter(); $generator = EccFactory::getNistCurves()->generator256();

        // Generate private key
        $privateKey = $generator->createPrivateKey();

        // Generate public key
        $publicKey = $privateKey->getPublicKey();

        // Serialize keys to DER format
        $privateKeySerializer = new DerPrivateKeySerializer($adapter);
        $publicKeySerializer = new DerPublicKeySerializer();

        $privateKeyDer = $privateKeySerializer->serialize($privateKey);
        $publicKeyDer = $publicKeySerializer->serialize($publicKey);

        // Base58 encode the 32-byte public key
        $publicKeyBytes = str_pad(gmp_export($publicKey->getPoint()->getX()), 32, "\0",     STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $base58 = new Base58();
        $walletAddress = $base58->encode($publicKeyBytes);
        return [
            'private_key' => bin2hex($privateKeyDer),
            'public_key' => bin2hex($publicKeyDer),
            'address' => $walletAddress
        ];
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return [$th->getMessage()];
    }
}

I want to get a correct private key which I can then use it to connect a wallet, send transactions and stuff like this
I tried to ask chatgpt but no helpful answer

You generate keys for curve P-256 (aka secp256r1 aka prime256v1), while Solana uses (a twisted Edwards curve birationally equivalent to) curve 25519. The former applies ECDSA as signature algorithm, the latter Ed25519, see e.g. here and here. A Libsodium wrapper for PHP is Sodium (though I don't know if this works with Laravel).

@Topaco Thank you, I had managed to correct it and now I'm good!

@Topaco can you give me a code example of how to sign a solana transaction using Laravel? I've been looking around for this for too long

I don't know which Solana library works with Laravel. You have to test that yourself. If you have found a promising approach but are stuck, you should post a new question with your code and a description of the problem.

I think you can use this code to view your private_key as a hex format
private_key_bytes = bytes.fromhex(privatekey)
print(private_key_bytes)

you can use the hex format to login in to the wallet address on phantom incase your automated transaction signing fails..
should look like this

ee6abb1689094e6763b93c9d9b1b220788643a9938bf6be66c441c7d2b3c3e94b5ac482de4c8c1e9957c7bd7dc1e3d8e45ee8c6667e7c5574b9b882a6c2bd18e

For automatic signings I believe you have to encode the privatekey to base64 and decode it during signing
